# Lock SlickGrid until the last "asyncPostRender" working out

Tags: javascript, cell, slickgrid

I want to lock (put semitransparent grey div on top of grid) grid until the last "asyncPostRender" is working out.

I have "asyncPostRender" that creates a complex markup in a grid cell. Markup creates one by onether from top to bottom cells. I want to block any interactions with not rendered cells until all is rendered.

How to do it? Or how to restate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hack around the intended use of this functionality.

The "async post renderers" in SlickGrid are a mechanism to add *optional* background decoration to cells so that the core performance and responsiveness of the grid/UI is not affected.  Think of it as stuff that is "nice to have".  Keep in mind that every time you scroll the rows are being removed from the DOM and recreated as the leave or enter the viewport.  By doing what you are describing you would block the UI every time the user scrolls.

Comment: so i have to write my own synchronous renderer which will attack grid after it rendred and create all the complex markup i need?

Comment: Use formatters to produce the HTML as a string and use existing grid events or events bubbled up to the container (i.e. event delegation) to provide interactivity.  If that is not enough, SlickGrid is probably not a good choice.